# Can I use "order by" with user input in oracle?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

I use the same procedure for several tasks. Each function also needs to use `ORDER BY` every time.
I want to use `ORDER BY` with user inputs.

I tried this but it didn't work.

```
  PROCEDURE GET_DEPARTMENT_LIST(ORDER_BY_PARAM IN VARCHAR2, DEPT_DATA OUT  T_CURSOR) IS
  V_CURSOR T_CURSOR;
  BEGIN
  OPEN V_CURSOR FOR
  SELECT GET_LIST(ORDER_BY_PARAM) FROM DUAL;
  DEPT_DATA  := V_CURSOR;
  END GET_DEPARTMENT_LIST;
  
  FUNCTION GET_LIST (PAR_ORDER_BY IN VARCHAR2)
     RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
    IS
      L_CR SYS_REFCURSOR;
    BEGIN
      OPEN L_CR FOR
          SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID, DEPARTMENT_CODE, DEPARTMENT_NAME 
          FROM DEPARTMENT ORDER BY PAR_ORDER_BY ASC;
      RETURN L_CR;
  END;
```

Procedure Executed Query :

```
VARIABLE RC REFCURSOR;
EXECUTE DEPARTMENT_PKG.GET_DEPARTMENT_LIST('DEPARTMENT_NAME', :RC);
PRINT RC;
```

Result :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can. For example:

```
SQL> create or replace function get_list (par_order_by in varchar2)
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    l_rc sys_refcursor;
  5  begin
  6    open l_rc for
  7      'select empno, ename, job, sal from emp where deptno = 10 order by ' || par_order_by;
  8    return l_rc;
  9  end;
 10  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select get_list('ename') result from dual;

RESULT
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- ---------- --------- ----------
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         2450
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT       5000
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           1300


SQL> select get_list('job, sal') result from dual;

RESULT
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- ---------- --------- ----------
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           1300
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         2450
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT       5000


SQL>
```

---

As you noticed, I created a function - for simplicity - instead of a procedure with an `OUT` parameter. If you have to use a procedure, no problem; it is the `ORDER BY` you had problem with, not the way you'll return the result to the caller.

---

**[EDIT: procedure that calls a function]**

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_dept_list (
  2     order_by_param  IN     VARCHAR2,
  3     dept_data          OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
  4  IS
  5  BEGIN
  6     OPEN dept_data FOR SELECT get_list (order_by_param) FROM DUAL;
  7  END get_dept_list;
  8  /

Procedure created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_list (par_order_by IN VARCHAR2)
  2     RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
  3  IS
  4     l_rc  SYS_REFCURSOR;
  5  BEGIN
  6     OPEN l_rc FOR
  7           'select empno, ename, job, sal from emp where deptno = 10 order by '
  8        || par_order_by;
  9
 10
 11     RETURN l_rc;
 12  END;
 13  /

Function created.
```

Sorted by ENAME:

```
SQL> var rc refcursor
SQL> exec get_dept_list('ename', :rc)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print rc

GET_LIST(:B1)
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- ---------- --------- ----------
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         2450
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT       5000
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           1300
```

Sorted by JOB:

```
SQL> exec get_dept_list('job', :rc)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print rc

GET_LIST(:B1)
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- ---------- --------- ----------
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           1300
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         2450
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT       5000
```

Sorted by SAL in descending order:

```
SQL> exec get_dept_list('sal desc', :rc)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print rc

GET_LIST(:B1)
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- ---------- --------- ----------
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT       5000
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         2450
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           1300


SQL>
```

Comment: I created the function and call function inside the procedure.

Comment: `VARIABLE RC REFCURSOR;
EXECUTE DEPARTMENT_PKG.GET_LIST('DEPARTMENT_NAME', :RC);
PRINT RC;`

Comment: This is how I run the procedure for the test. The data is returned but sorting does not work by passing the parameter.

Comment: It works for me; can't tell why it doesn't work for you as you didn't post code you use, nor sample data which would let *us* see it for ourselves. Consider editing the original question you posted by providing additional info.

Comment: Check now. I Correct them.

Comment: If you have a closer look at the differences between your function and mine, you'll notice that I enclosed SELECT statement into **single quotes** and **concatenated** the ORDER BY clause, while you didn't do that. What's the point in me posting code you don't follow?

Comment: I also tried this way. If I used **single quotes** and **concatenated** no data would be returned here.

Comment: I edited the answer and posted both procedure and function, along with several examples. Looks OK to me. I don't have your tables so I used Scott's sample schema.

Comment: Here's the problem. There must be a space after the `ORDER BY '` command. Thank you!

Comment: I believe that's what my code already contains :) You're welcome, I'm glad if it helped.